# How to data transfer one database to another database using multi-thread?

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I have 2 million data my snowflake database and the data transfer to cassandra database. It's transfer fine. But to late. So I decided use multi-thread. It's possible ?. If possible how to transfer my data one database to another database using multi-thread.    Thanks

Comment: I don't know the two kinds of databases. I believe you can fetch with pagination, like 1 to 100000, and 100001 to 200000 etc. You can start new thread with different index, and deal pages one by one.

Comment: @Bejond can you give some link for my reference ?

Comment: I think https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/limit.html pagination would help. Suppose you have 200 results to transfer. One thread fetch 1 to 100 results, another thread for 101 to 200.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time ,@Bejond